# Creating azure search service with DocumentDb as resource for service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I already set up DocumentDb and uploaded the documents to DocumentDb.

My JSON documents have data nested upto 4 levels, eg:-

```
{
  id: '12345',
  properties:
  {
      Accessories:
      {
            watch:1,
            WristBands: [{
                  blue:1, 
                  red: 2}]
                  }
            }
  Name: Leo,
  Age: 24
}
```

I want to use azure search service for able to search upto the last level(e.g. The count of wristband colour i.e. blue:1). I have setup the service as well.

I want some help in creating the index and the indexer for such nested data in C# so that I can query the service.
Already found, how to use DataType.Collection(DataType.String), but this supports till level 2.

Classes can also be made for each sub-level but have no idea how to define them during indexing. Refered to example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more tutorial on setting up Azure Search indexer for DocumentDB: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-search-indexer/.

+1 on Kirk Evans' blog post, which shows how to flatten the JSON document. The idea is to leverage the optional query property under container in the data source creation request, and use a join query in that place.

Comment: Thank you both for your wonderful help. Got your point. Was able to successfully flatten my data using the Azure Portal(The optional query property). 
Just 1 more question. how can we leverage this in .Net code is we want to achieve the whole flattening process from the code.

Comment: Hi Leo, if I understand your question correctly, you are trying to create a DocumentDB datasource for Azure Search with the flatten JSON query passed in from Azure Search .NET SDK. I am not an expert of Azure Search. By scanning through the SDK APIs, I found you could set DataSource.Container.Query property when you create a new DataSource. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, you got me right. But I could not find the exact syntax for setting query property.

Comment: From Azure Search .NET API doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.search.models.datasource.aspx), what you need to do is to construct a DataSource object and set its Container.Query property. You could follow the REST example I posted to get the query syntax. Once all the needed properties of the DataSource object have been set, you could use the following API to create the data source in Azure Search Service: public static DataSource Create(
 this IDataSourcesOperations operations,
 DataSource dataSource,
 SearchRequestOptions searchRequestOptions = null
)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Search does not support nested documents.  As you can see from our [Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) page, this by far the most requested feature so it is something that we are very interested in adding (please cast your vote here if you don't mind).  Unfortunately, we do not yet have a timeline on when we will have it implemented yet.

In the meantime, for some applications it is realistic to either flatten the JSON documents or to leverage collection types.  For more details on flattening documents, Kirk Evans has a really good [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/03/09/indexing-documentdb-with-azure-seach/) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please answer the same the same question I asked Lenging i.e. achieving "flattening the data" using the .NET library.